# Cache SOAP search results from external web service

Tags: caching, services

I've inherited an older Drupal 6 site which calls an external SOAP web service which not only takes a while to query and display results (approx. 5 seconds) but also re-queries the web service when any parameters are changed (e.g. results per page or ordering).

I am considering what efficiency improvements I can make (such as not re-querying the web service when some parameters are changed) but that will involve caching the initial responses, etc.

Was looking for suggestions that I might not have considered, importing the results into nodes isn't really an option due to the potential number of results

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could hack together a module that queries the external site and then populates an Apache Solr search database, then you could simply use the [Apache Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module on read-only to look at the data on your site...